# Reading a text written in different language scripts (Western, Georgian)

Tags: python, text, character

I made a script for reading a grammar book of Georgian verbs in English. It  visualizes correctly the Georgian and English characters from the text on the screen however when it stores the information in a list, the Georgian characters assume a different representation. See an example below. Note tha t I am using Python release 2.7.

Print on computer screen and corresponding to the exact content in the text

10.1. Conjugation of transitive verbs

10.1.1. წერს – he/she writes

I სერია

Stored on a list

```
[['10.1.', 'Conjugation', 'of', 'transitive', 'verbs'], [], ['10.1.1.', '\xe1\x83\xac\xe1\x83\x94\xe1\x83\xa0\xe1\x83\xa1', '\xe2\x80\x93', 'he/she', 'writes'], [], ['I', '\xe1\x83\xa1\xe1\x83\x94\xe1\x83\xa0\xe1\x83\x98\xe1\x83\x90'], [], []]
```

The Georgian characters are now represents by strings containing characters like '\xe1\xac'. Please can you help me to handle Georgian alphabet? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is how Python 2.7 unicode characters will be represented when you print a list containing them. Is this an issue for any particular reason? The actual strings aren't changing...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to search whether a word (verb stem) is inside another word (verbal form).  I wonder  what would happen if I use Python 3.3. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why Python 3.3? That is over 5 years old. Why not Python 3.6? But what is stopping you from doing it in Python 2.7?

Comment: Nope, I do not want to switch to other release, I am with Python 2.7. It was just a question.

Comment: Well, if you are going to be dealing with unicode text a lot, then Python 3 is the way to go... but again, what is stopping you here with Python 2.7?

Comment: I was not sure whether the Georgian characters were correctly recognized. That's all.

Comment: They are. Those are escape-sequences representing raw-bytes. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to learn more about strings and unicode in Python 2.

Comment: I was reading that document and then I decided to post a query here. Do you think there will be some possible issues in using that escape-sequences for match searches in Georgian texts.

Comment: That is just how it is being printed to the screen - the strings themselves are *exactly the same*. Where it becomes problematic for you is if you mix encodings

Comment: It's fine then! Thank you very much!